# Dust.js context issue?

Tags: templates, scope, dust.js

I have the following partial:

```
<ul class="navbar">
    {#nav_links}
    <li class="navbar__link {?sub_menu}more{/sub_menu}">
        <a href="/{link}">{label}</a>
        {?sub_menu}
        <ul class="navbar__link--sub">
            {#sub_menu}
            <li class="navbar__link--sub {?sub_menu}more{/sub_menu}">
                <a href="/{link}">{label}</a>
            </li>
            {/sub_menu}
        </ul>
        {/sub_menu}
    </li>
    {/nav_links}
</ul>
```

With JSON:

```
{
    title: "page title",
    nav_links: [
        {
            link: "home",
            label:"Home"
        },
        {
            link: "products",
            label:"Products",
            sub_menu: [
                {link: "link1", label: "Product A"},
                {link: "link2", label: "Product B"},
                {link: "link3", label: "Products C", sub_menu: [
                    {link: "link3-1", label: "Sub Product A"},
                    {link: "link3-2", label: "Sub Product B"}
                ]},
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue I've run into is the nested sub_menu property, all sub menu items add the `more` class regardless if they have a nested `sub_menu` or not. I thought the context would have shifted like it does with `link` and `label`, however it seems to still refer to the initial `sub_menu` like the first conditional and section tags do. I've renamed the nested `sub_menu` property in the JSON and partial tag, context works correctly then. Is there a way to still use the `sub_menu` property name? Or reference the child property such as `sub_menu.sub_menu`?

Comment: Put together a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g94g2pqh/1/ , You can see all submenu list elements render red, and the first two end up using their parent `sub_menu`... Which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Dust will walk up the context if it doesn't find a key at a certain level. However, you're wanting to explicitly check only the current level of the context. To do this in Dust, prefix the key with a dot:

`<li class="navbar__link--sub {?.sub_menu}more{/sub_menu}">`

Comment: Any relevant information on this syntax that you can link me to? I've seen other StackOverflow questions use the `.` prefix with `#` section tags too, is this usually something I should do with all tags unless I want Dust to find context for the key elsewhere?